# Find median in four (individually) sorted arrays with O(1) space

Tags: arrays, algorithm, median

I have an assignment to find a median in 4 individually sorted arrays.

A median is defined as the element that is in the middle of the array (at index floor(N/2))

Requirements:

1. time complexity: linear to the size of the combined array
2. space complexity: O(1)

I know how to find a median in 2 sorted arrays with O(1) space and O(logn) time, but I cant find a good solution for 4 arrays that meets the requirement of O(1) space.

I have tried to adjust the algorithm for 3 arrays but it didn't work very well for me.

example for my assignment:

```
A = {1 5 10 15 20}
B = {2 3 4 6 7}
C = {25 30 35 40 45}
D = {8 9 90 100 145}

median(A,B,C,D) = 10
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *How* is this different from *Find median in two (individually) sorted arrays with O(1) space*? Please sketch a/the solution for the latter and what your difficulty to applying it to the *k* arrays variant is.

Comment: (*If* the arrays are of widely different length, the task becomes slightly more challenging.)

Comment: By all means, sketch your `3 arrays` approach in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Think of a single unsorted array**

Consider thinking about the 4 arrays as a single *unsorted* array, broken into 4 parts. If you can modify the arrays, you can sort all 4 arrays as if 1 by swapping values between them (some optimizations can be made since you know the 4 arrays are sorted). Once you've sorted the arrays up to n/2 (where n is the aggregate length of the 4 arrays), just return the middle value of all 4.

**Some Code**

The implementation below begins to make multiple arrays function like a single one. I've implemented `get`, `set`, and `length` methods, the basis for any array. All that needs to happen now is for the class' data to be sorted (possibly up to n/2) using `get(int)`, `set(int,int)`, and `length()`, and a method which returns the median value `median()`.

Perhaps there is a way to get the median value of an array in a single pass, I cannot think of it however. A quick sort and lookup will perform in O(nLogn) time complexity, only a single pass will reduce this to O(n) (linear to the size of the array).

There is also room for further optimization by sorting only up to n/2 within the median method, also when caching (i,j) pairs for each element when doing so.

```
int median( int[] a1, int[] a2, int[] a3, int[] a4 ) {
    MultiIntArray array = new MultiIntArray( a1, a2, a3, a4 );
    array.sort();
    return array.get( array.length() / 2 );
}
```

```
public class MultiIntArray {

    private int[][] data;

    public MultiIntArray( int[]... data ) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void sort() {
        // FOR YOU TO IMPLEMENT
    }

    public int length() {
        int length = 0;
        for ( int[] array : data ) {
            length += array.length;
        }
        return length;
    }

    public int get( int index ) {
        int i = 0;
        while ( index >= data[i].length ) {
            index -= data[i].length;
            i += 1;
        }
        return data[i][index];
    }

    public void set( int index, int value ) {
        int i = 0;
        while ( index >= data[i].length ) {
            index -= data[i].length;
            i += 1;
        }
        data[i][index] = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the restriction "time complexity is the size of the combined arrays" it is trivial, you just pick the smallest of the first elements of four arrays n/2 times. No clever algorithm needed.

I'm sure you can do it significantly faster.

Comment: Then you'd get the smallest of the 4 arrays, not the median.